# Recursive generator of random algebraic expressions tree issue

Tags: java

## Problem description

I am trying to write a math test for my little son.
Such test must generate a list of random algebraic expressions according to certain rules and check the correctness of solution.

In particular, I want to generate expressions consisting strictly of a given number of operators that are selected from a certain list.
For example *generate a list of expression consisting of 3 operators of addition and subtraction in random order* like:

- 12 - (5 + 2) + 2
- 3 + 4 - 2 + 10
- and so on

To represent and calculate the expression, I use the *binary expression tree* structure.
Each tree consists of either a `Leaf` or a `Node` that contains an `Operator` and two subtrees.
This is a simple recursive structure and I want to work with it only recursively.
No setters in the classes of the tree. I can only use constructors to create a tree.

##### Leaf class

```
public final class Leaf implements Expression {

    private final int value;
    
    public Leaf(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

##### Node Class

```
public final class Node implements Expression {

    private final Operator operator;
    private final Expression left;
    private final Expression right;
    
    public Node(@NotNull Operator operator, 
                @NotNull Expression left,
                @NotNull Expression right) {
        this.operator = operator;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

And `Operator` is a simple `Enum` type. I simplify my classes for the purposes of this question.

## My issue

I am trying to build an expression based on the following rules:

- There should be at least one operator in the expression, so my tree always starts from the `Node`.
- I choose a random operator from a given list and increase the number of operators used
- While this number less than the given number of operators I construct the left and rights subtree for current `Node`.
- The left subtree can be randomly either a `Leaf` or `Node`
- The right subtree can also be either a `Leaf` or `Node`, but if the left subtree is a `Leaf` and there are still unused operators, then the right must be a `Node`.

I wrote such an expression builder:

```
public class SmartExpressionBuilder {

    private final Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    private final List<Operator> allowedOperators;
    private final int numberOfOperators;

    public SmartExpressionBuilder(List<Operator> allowedOperators, int numberOfOperators) {
        this.allowedOperators = allowedOperators;
        this.numberOfOperators = numberOfOperators;
    }

    private int operatorsUsed;

    public Expression build() {
        operatorsUsed = 0;
        return helper();
    }

    private Expression helper() {
        if (operatorsUsed == numberOfOperators) return randomLeaf();

        Operator op = randomOperator();

        Expression left = random.nextBoolean() ? helper() : randomLeaf();
        Expression right = (left instanceof Leaf || random.nextBoolean()) ? helper() : randomLeaf();

        return new Node(op, left, right);
    }

    private Operator randomOperator() {
        operatorsUsed++;
        return allowedOperators.get(random.nextInt(allowedOperators.size()));
    }

    private Leaf randomLeaf() {
        return new Leaf(random.nextInt(1, 10));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final var builder = new SmartExpressionBuilder(List.of(Operator.ADD, Operator.SUB), 4);
        IntStream.range(0, 10)
                .mapToObj(ignored -> builder.build())
                .forEach(exp -> {
                    System.out.printf("%s = %d%n", exp.infix(), exp.evaluate());
                    TreePrinter.print(exp);
                });
    }
}
```

This works in principle. In the sense that a tree really builds with a given number of operators.
But there's a problem.
I get nodes looks like this:

```
    Node                Node
   /    \      or      /    \
 Leaf  Node          Node  Leaf
```

For example my actual expression and tree may looks like this:

```
4 + 4 - (1 + 3) - 2 = 2
            +
    4               -
                -       2
              4   +        
                 1 3
```

but i never get tree like this:

```
    Node                  +
   /    \        or    -     +
 Node  Node           5 2  2   -
                              6 1
```

I understand what the essence of the problem is.
In my recursive function, I always go into the left tree first.
And every time my random generates an the `Node` is in the left subtree, and not the `Leaf`, recursion dive deeper and deeper int the left subtree until unused operators ends.
This means that if an `Node` appeared in the left subtree, then `Node` cannot appear in the right at the same depths of tree.

I broke my brain, but did not figure out how to solve this problem without abandoning the recursive construction of my tree.

I would be very grateful for any ideas how build nodes of this kind

```
    Node
   /    \
 Node  Node
```

Comment: @chptr-one Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also add your code to the question itself, not on an external site. Currently your code results in a StackOverflowError. Also, keep in mind that you are using random numbers and you could simply have "bad luck" in generating a `Leaf` or a `Node` instance.

Comment: @chptr-one Please [edit] your question to include the trees you want to build. Provide example trees with a big enough number of operators to use. Explain in detail how and why the trees should generate the `Leaf` and `Node` instances in such a way and how you want them.

Comment: @Progman I fixed a problem with StackOverflowException

Comment: @Progman I tested this generator on two hundred expressions and I have never received two operators at one depth of a tree. Only a `Leaf` with the `Node` in two possible combinations. This is clearly not my bad luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be very difficult to get balanced trees this way - you have to tune it very carefully for the left tree to probably give you half the operators. I don't think it's worth it.

Instead, I would pick the target number of operators at the top level - that would be a minimum plus some random range to generate larger or smaller expressions - and then randomly assign some of them to each subtree. So you have a recursive call that takes a `size` parameter; if `size==0`, generate a leaf, otherwise make a node, and split `size-1` into a `leftSize` and `rightSize` to pass to the recursive calls.

Here's some rough pseudocode (I don't write much Java these days, but hopefully it makes the algorithm clear)

```
private Expression build(int size){
  if (size == 0) return buildLeaf()
  else {
    leftSize = randomInt(size-1)
    rightSize = size - 1 - leftSize
    leftTree = build(leftSize)
    rightTree = build(rightSize)
    return buildNode(leftTree, rightTree, getRandomOperator())
   }
}
```

Does that make sense and work for you?

Comment: A similar idea occurred to me, but it seemed to me quite difficult to implement. I will try to do this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I rewritten my method, as [Edward Peters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6016064/edward-peters) suggested.

At each step of recursion, I randomly determine how many `Node`'s will be in the left and right trees (the sum of these numbers at the first step should be equal to the required number of operators in the expression), and return the `Leaf` if the number of nodes turns out to zero.

It's work just fine.

```
public Expression build(int numberOfOperators) {                                                         
    if (numberOfOperators == 0) return randomLeaf();                                                     
                                                                                                         
    int leftNodes = random.nextInt(numberOfOperators);                                                   
    int rightNodes = numberOfOperators - leftNodes - 1;                                                  
                                                                                            
    return new Node(randomOperator(), build(leftNodes), build(rightNodes));                                                      
}
```

One example of resulting expression tree:

```
5 + 5 - (4 + 7) = -1

   -                   Node
 +   +    or     Node        Node
5 5 4 7       Leaf  Leaf  Leaf  Leaf
```